# How do I update an item in a specific nested dictionary in mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, discord.py, pymongo

I have 3 dictionaries stored online in MongoDB and I want to access
a specific item in a specific dictionary and update it with a different item but I don't know how to do that. I've tried multiple ways but none seemed to work. I don't want to access the item in a dictionary by the dictionary's index because there will be more dictionaries and I would need to edit the code every time. I've tried to update it with this code but, it doesn't work. Anyone know the solution to this?

```py
@client.command()
async def warn(ctx, user: discord.User, reason: Optional[str] = None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    guild_id = ctx.guild.id
    warn_id = f"{uid.uuid1()}"  # Randomly generated warning ID
    if reason is None:
        reason = "No reason given!"  # reason
    warn_count = 1
    for i in role_ids:
        if role_ids[i]["_id"] == ctx.guild.id:
            for _user in range(0, len(role_ids[i]["logs"]["warn_logs"]["users"])):
                # if role_ids[i]["logs"]["warn_logs"]["users"][_user]:
                if f"{user.id}" in role_ids[i]["logs"]["warn_logs"]["users"][_user]:
                    for e in range(0, len(role_ids[i]["logs"]["warn_logs"]["users"][_user][f"{user.id}"]["warnings"])):
                        if f"warning_{warn_count}" in \
                                role_ids[i]["logs"]["warn_logs"]["users"][_user][f"{user.id}"]["warnings"][e]:
                            warn_count += 1
                            pass
                        else:
                            # role_ids[i]["logs"]["warn_logs"]["users"][_user][f"{user.id}"]["warnings"][e+1]
                            my_dict = {"$set": {
                                f"warning_{warn_count}": {"author": f"{ctx.author.id}",
                                                          "reason": reason,
                                                          "warn_id": warn_id},
                                "warning_0":""}}
                            mongo_col.find_one_and_update({"_id": ctx.guild.id, "logs": {
                                "warn_logs": {"users": [{f"{user.id}": {"warnings": [{"warning_0": ""}]}}]}}}, my_dict)
```

[image: The dictionaries and the item I want to access.]

Comment: Could you give more insight on the data model

Comment: If this is what you're looking for then (https://imgur.com/a/9hrYRMn). These are pictures of how the data looks like. The 2nd picture is the 1st dictionary expanded.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gXjze0fP This is the dictionary that i'm searching through looks like. Because at the end of every change in the database, i call a function that will take all the info from the database and store it in a global dictionary within the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't find a solution to my problem, but I was able to think of an alternative method which is probably not as efficient but does the job quite well. I took all the data from the mongodb collection and saved it in a local dictionary variable, then used the local variable to search/edit data and posted it back to mongodb with the "update_one" method.